# Рекурсия Python

Tags: python, рекурсия

Я новичок в программировании, прошу Вас помочь с рекурсивным- консольным меню!

Есть меню с 4-а пунктами
Если выбрать 1й, в консоли попросит ввести данные товара, которые отправляются в массив
----после ввода товара консоль дальше принимает ввод, в котором при вводе цифры возврата оно        ----открывает главное меню либо выйти
2й выводит все что есть в массиве
----и также можно ввести возврат в мейн-меню либо выйти
3й возвращает в главное меню
4й выход

Comment: Да рекурсия-то тут особо и не нужна.

Comment: ок, дайте пожалуйста намек куда двигаться=)

Comment: А с чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле просто через if else можно, и вложенные функции. Это не совсем рекурсия, что-то вроде этого, ну если я правильно понял ваше желание.

```
def function1():
        #Действия функции 1
def function2():
        #Действия функции 2
def function3():
        #Действия функции 3
def function4():
        #Действия функции 4
def main_function(function_checker):
     if function_checker == 1:
          function1
     elif function_checker == 2:
          function2
     elif function_checker == 3:
          function3
     elif function_checker == 4:
          function4
     else:
          print('Функция не найдена')
main_function(int(input))
```

Comment: неверный код...